# BigInteger exponentiation with BigInteger number: ArithmeticException, would overflow supported range

Tags: java, exponentiation

I'm building the DSA algorithm. But I had a problem when ranking BigInteger numbers with other BigInteger numbers. This is the formula I want to use:

`v = ((g^u1 * y^u2) mod p) mod q`

This is the code I made:

`BigInteger v = g.pow(u1.intValue()).multiply(y.pow(u2.intValue())).mod(p).mod(q);`

When running the script, the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range
        at java.math.BigInteger.reportOverflow(Unknown Source)
        at java.math.BigInteger.pow(Unknown Source)
        at DSAVerifying.main(DSAVerifying.java:38)
```

Comment: Use [`modPow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)) instead of doing a `pow` first and a `mod` later.

Comment: It turns out there are [mathematical tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) that you can use to calculate things of the form a^b mod c, when calculating it by brute force would create very large numbers, and `modPow` uses exactly those tricks.

Comment: @luk2302 I'm having a hard time using modPow when the documentation is different from the one I implemented

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question to explain exactly how you are "having a hard time" and how "the documentation is different from the one I implemented".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on my comment and because I could not find a duplicate: use [`modPow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger))!

The problem here is that `g^u1` (and `y^u2`) is REALLY large. But very often when dealing with powers in maths you have a mod statement following it and that simplifies stuff a lot: generally `a ^ b mod c` can be expressed as `((((a * a) mod c) * a) mod c) * a) mod c .....` (b times). And that is basically what `modPow` does, it applies the `mod` during the exponation. This will return the same number but will not overflow. They are mathematically identical, but one can be calculated by a computer with reasonable effort while the other cannot. It is up to you as the developer to be smart and simplify or rephrase the expression you want to solve in a way that a computer can properly handle.

```
BigInteger v = g.modPow(u1, p).multiply(y.modPow(u2, p)).mod(p).mod(q);
```

---

Basically to compute `(6 ^ 10 mod 7)` you do not ever want to first calculate `6 ^ 10` and then apply the `mod 7` but instead do `6 * 6 mod 7 = 36 mod 7 = 1 => 1 * 6 mod 7 = 6 => 6 * 6 mod 7 = 36 mod 7 = 1 => ...` and you can see that the only values you deal with are 1 and 6 instead of `60466176` (which is `6^10`).

Comment: `u1.intValue()` -> `u1`.  `u2.intValue()` -> `u2`.  See [modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigInteger))