# Modulo 10^9+7 in java

Tags: java, modulo

I am trying to use Modulo 10^9+7 (or 1000000007) with a very large `long` number but I am not getting the correct result.

```
long M = 1000000007;
int num = 212;
int val = 9;
long sol = (long)Math.pow(val,num) % M ;
```

I should get the output as

```
541416750(mod10^9+7)
```

but what I am getting is

```
291172003
```

Comment: 9^212 overflow, try with BigInteger

Comment: Check the max value of `long` - it's about 20 digits long. On the other hand, 9^212 is much bigger than that.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: I have also tried using ```((Math.pow(9,101) % M ) * (Math.pow(9,111) % M) % M)``` but still i havent got the correct answer

Comment: @SauravShrivastav, It is normal, check the result of a power of 101, it's not fit in a 64 bits integer. Use something that allow you to deal with very large Integer

Comment: @thibsc thats why i am using long and with every step i am taking the modulus of that number i.e. ```((Math.pow(9,101) % M ) * (Math.pow(9,111) % M) % M)```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigInteger exponentiation with BigInteger number: ArithmeticException, would overflow supported range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160173/biginteger-exponentiation-with-biginteger-number-arithmeticexception-would-ove)

Comment: *"with every step i am taking the modulus"* - no, you do not. `Math.pow(9,101)` is already too large, you need to mod in between the multiplication within the `pow`.

Comment: @luk2302 Yea i thought so and thats why I am here to find a solution for it. Can you please suggest an answer for the same. Thanks

Comment: Yes: the answer I already linked. Or do not use `pow` but write your own that mods between the multiplications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**9<sup>12</sup>** overflows long.

Also double `Math.pow` loses precision, so corrupts the modulo value.
(If an 8 byte long overflows, an 8 byte double can merely approximate the value, especially losing least significant digits.)

One could use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) for a straight-forward solution.

You might also exploit **a * b % n == ((a % n) * (b % n)) % n** to reduce the power:

```
long modPow(int var, int num) {
    long m = 1;
    while (num > 0) {
        m = (m * var) % M;
        --num;
    }
    return m;
}
```

This is not the best solution, but the question reeks of math & programming class,
because of the modulo knowledge.

As M is an int, the return value could be an int, casted.

Comment: I tried this function, and it returns an incorrect result.